# the effect of Visas refusals on UK Spouse Visa application

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, spouses

Do previous UK Visitor Visa and United states Visa refusals affect UK spouse Visa application in the future if all the requirements of the spouse Visa have been provided ?
PS: the reasons for refusals are not being able to show ties to my home country or to the country where i reside.

Comment: Do you mean a visa to allow your spouse to live with you in the UK? If so then this question belongs on [expatriates.se]. Please ask it there.

Comment: It would probably depend on the refusal reason(s). For example, insufficient evidence of intention to return to home country wouldn’t be relevant for a spouse visa application. You should add the reason(s) to your question to help you get more meaningful answers.

Comment: @DJClayworth No sir, Visa to allow me to live with my spouse in the UK, but i can only apply for it next year so i can meet all the requirements

Comment: @Traveller the reasons are not being able to show ties to my country or to the country I reside in, do you it’s fine for this reason or will it affect spouse visa application? Thank you for your reply

Comment: @AnasHammad This site is for questions about short term travel, like vacations. Questions about applying to live in other countries belong on another site, which is called [expatriates.se]. Please ask your question there.